# qooxdoo qx.data.Array replace

Tags: qooxdoo

Is there a way to replace a qx.data.Array?  I see methods for a whole lot of other options in the API but not that. I know I can do a removeAll() and then append new items, but that fires some events in my controller that I wish wouldn't fire. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the splice method which will work out fine. You can delete the whole content of the array and append new items in one call.

Comment: Thanks @Martin, I looked at that and was "scared off" by the fact that is says for every new item added or removed an event is fired and I was trying to steer clear of multiple events firing. I'm using a SelectBox with a controller that updates the ListItems in that list when the array is changed. I have a changeSelection listener on the SelectBox and it gets fired a lot... so I handled it with a if(e.getData().length>0){ call, but that's not perfect by any means.

Comment: We already changed that. Only one event is fired for splice now. :) Will be sure in the 2.0 release.